# C++ input not being accepted using cin

Tags: c++

I've just started programming and I tried to write a simple program to check if the number is even, print YES if it is or else print NO.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int w;
    int remainder;
    
    cout << "Enter the number : ";
    
    cin >> w ; 
    remainder = w % 4;
    
    if(remainder==0) 
        cout << "\nYes " << endl; 
    
    else
        cout << "\nNO " << endl; 


    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this program, the following output comes up:

```
$g++ -o main *.cpp
$main
Enter the number : 
Yes
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, the code you show and the compilation command should work as expected

Comment: What happens if you add a `<< std::endl` after the first cout ? How exactly does the session happen? What is your input?

Comment: What happens if you init `w`? With 1? With 4? I.e. what makes you think that the input is not accepted?

Comment: When I init w with 1 it displays NO and Yes with 4.

Comment: Online compilers usually also allow you to provide input. What is yours?

Comment: @anastaciu It doesn't ask the user input and directly skips to the print statement.

Comment: I'm using geek for geeks online compiler.

Comment: Your input must be placed in the *input* field of the compiler, that's how online compilers usually work. You don't see it in the command line.

Comment: @Cassandra, try this one, it allows you to write the input in the command line: https://repl.it/@anastaciu/DiscreteSleepyOutsourcing

Comment: @Cassandra also note that to check for even numbers you should check for the remainder of the division by 2, not by 4.

Comment: I initially close-voted for lack of debugging details. Meanwhile there is more info (thanks). Especially the proposed experiment with inits to 1 and 4 clearly shows that you indeed fail to readd input. With the shown code that cannot be reproduced, assuming that there IS any input. You do not provide enough information on analysing that. With the given info (if consdiered sufficient, like I do) the problem is not reproducable. If the info is not considered sufficient, then the question still lacks debugging info. Either way, I consider the question close-worthy.

Answer (score 0):

There is one logical error there.

```
remainder = w% 2;  // must be.
```

The problem you reported may be related to the proqram you are using. I am using Visual Studio and it didn't cause any problems for me. But you can also write the conditions using parentheses:

```
if(remainder==0) {
    cout << "\nYes " << endl; 
}
else {
    cout << "\nNO " << endl; 
}
```

and try them out. Maybe works. (why **maybe** ? You working on an online compiler. In this case, I cannot guarantee anything)

---

**WHY %2**

for example: "2% 4" would answer 2. And this can sometimes cause problems for online compilers. The most logical thing is to get a plain answer by doing "% 2". 2% 2 = 0 this gives us a smoother answer.

```
1% 2 = 1,
2% 2 = 0,
3% 2 = 1
```

1 means: Not even number.
0 means:  Even number.

---

The best way is not to try to fix online compilers errors . Because if you develop your code for a corrupt compiler then you will have trouble with a decent compiler. **I recommend having a normal non-online compiler.**

Solving the problem with the sleep function does not necessarily mean you have solved the problem. This path can create a lot of problems for you when developing larger programs.

Comment: The reported problem is a failure to read input. How is that related to the applied modulo? Always using `{}` is a philosophy I also subscribe to, but it is also unrelated to the problem. I get the impression that you missed the discussion of likely problems in the comments. Your answer seems not to address the problem, does not explain anything. The speculation on the used "program" is not clear enough. I am personally not a fan of "maybe", "try this" in answers. Please try to be more assertive.

Comment: @Yunnosch Remember that you are working in the Online Compiler. We are trying to solve something illogical right now. The first problem is the online compiler. And we don't know how it can react to the codes. Just trying can sometimes fix big problems.

Answer (score 0):

try using this..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int w;
    cout<<"Enter the number : ";
    cin>>w;
    string s=(w%2==0)?"even number":"odd number";
    cout<<w<<" is a "<<s;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why? Do you need your code tested? Please elaborate the experiment you want OP to perform. What result would result in what insight? What does each of the results you expect mean for the analysis?

Comment: We need the solution of existing code, not a new code

Comment: your program works absolutely fine in my compiler there can be problem in your compiler

Comment: If compiler issues are there i recommend you to use online compiler like https://repl.it/languages/cpp